# Edit XML file (remove node and add new one)

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have problems to deal with XML in PHP. What i want is to remove a not needed element and replace it with a other one.

Let's say the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<software>
    <info>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <lasterror>1386680712</lasterror>
    </info>
    <decryption>
        <funcgroup siglength="86">
            <func>
                <name>Mk</name>
                <args>$a</args>
                <code>XXXX</code>
            </func>
            <func>
                <name>Nk</name>
                <args>$a,$b</args>
                <code>XXXX</code>
            </func>
        </funcgroup>
    </decryption>
</software>
```

PHP Code:

```
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$domtree->loadXML(file_get_contents('test.xml'));

$thedocument = $domtree->documentElement;

$list = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('funcgroup');
foreach ($list as $domElement) {
    $sig_length = $domElement->getAttribute('siglength');
    if($sig_length == $signature_length) {
        $domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement);
        break;
    }
}

$some_stuff = $domtree->getElementsByTagName('software');
$some_stuff = $domtree->getElementsByTagName('decryption');
$funcgroup = $domtree->appendChild($domtree->createElement('funcgroup'));
$funcgroup->setAttribute('siglength', $signature_length);

$func = $funcgroup->appendChild($domtree->createElement('func'));
$func->appendChild($domtree->createElement('name', $outer_element[0]));
$func->appendChild($domtree->createElement('args', $outer_element[1]));
$code = $func->appendChild($domtree->createElement('code'));
$code->appendChild($domtree->createTextNode($outer_element[2]));
```

Note: I removed some stuff otherwise it would get too complicated i guess. The above code shows what i do, but without some other loops and variables which are not needed in that question. Every variable (and array) is defined. So don't worry about that.

What i want is to remove the whole `<funcgroup siglength="86">` in order to replace it with a different one.

The script works fine, but there is one problem in the output XML. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<software>
    <info>
        <version>6.3</version>
        <lasterror>1386680712</lasterror>
    </info>
    <decryption/>
</software>
<funcgroup siglength="86">
<func>
    <name>Nk</name>
    <args>$a</args>
    <code>YYYYY</code>
</func>
<func>
    <name>Ok</name>
    <args>$a,$b</args>
    <code>YYYY</code>
</func>
</funcgroup>
```

As you can see, the closing `software` and `decryption` tags are on the wrong place now.

How can i fix that? I spent hours but can't find a working solution.

The problem is caused by the `removeChild()` since it works fine if i do not remove something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your new child node to the document itself (instead of the `decryption` node), which is not what you want

```
$domtree->appendChild
```

Instead you should:

```
$decryption = $domtree->getElementsByTagName('decryption')->item(0);
$funcgroup = $decryption->appendChild($domtree->createElement('funcgroup'));
```

**Edit:**

You can edit the text value of the `lasterror` node by doin:

```
$domtree->getElementsByTagName('lasterror')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue = "New value";
```

Consult the documentation of the [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) and [DOMNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) class to see what else you can do with it.

Comment: Thanks but now i get `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::appendChild()`. XML is so confusing LOL. Especially when you never had to deal with it before. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Michael Corrected - item(0) was missing.

Comment: Oh man :D Thank you so much! You have no idea how happy i am now.. Wasted so much time on that. Thank you! <3

Comment: Btw. Do you know how i can edit the `lasterror` value? Should i just delete the whole node and reqrite it then? Or maybe just with regex? That's the last thing i need to do with that XML stuff.